# Are there any simple and yet secure encryption algorithms?

Tags: encryption, aes, block-cipher, algorithm-design

Being very new to C++ and cryptography, I finally managed to implement a version of the Vinegere algorithm. I would like to try something a bit more complicated. I have looked at AES and DES and others like them, but I was wondering if there is something simpler. Something that might use some of the same basic ideas as AES, but is much simpler. Some kind of block cipher maybe?

So I am asking for suggestions for a block cipher that is much simpler than AES, but more complex than a basic substitution algorithm. I have by the way looked into the method used in the Enigma-machines, but from what I understand they do "basically" the same as Vigenere.

Comment: Try [TEA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_Encryption_Algorithm). It is simple, secure (except for related-key attacks, and limits inherent to its 64-bit block size), and acceptably fast for many uses.

Comment: If it doesn't have to be a block cipher, RC4 would be a good one to look at.

Comment: @fgrieu I'd recommend XTEA, it is as simple as TEA but, as far as we know, more secure.

Comment: @ChrisSmith: Why would XTEA be more secure than TEA? Except for related-key attacks and the fact that each key trivially has 3 other equivalent keys, reducing TEA's key space to 126 bits, I know no weakness of TEA. On the other hand, a casual reading of [Meet-in-the-Middle Attacks on Reduced-Round XTEA](http://www.cosic.esat.kuleuven.be/publications/article-1505.pdf) seems to indicate that XTEA has less security margin than TEA in both the single-key and related-key settings. Not all revisions/extensions are improvements, and I feel TEA is more time-tested than XTEA is.

Comment: @fgrieu thanks for the suggestion. This looks like exactly what I want. I have been reading in a book about the Feistel structure, the TEA looks like that. So that is probably a good place to start.

Comment: @fgrieu I consider the related-key attack on TEA more severe than the attacks on XTEA.  I did not say that all revisions are improvements, I wouldn't use XXTEA for example.

Comment: @ChrisSmith: One simply does not need ANY resistance to related keys attacks in normal uses of a block cipher, where the key is secret and random. If a related-key attack is to fear, that's a tell-tale sign of misuse. This a lesson from the XBOX TEA fiasco (which IIRC just used the obvious equivalent keys).

Comment: @fgrieu Under most scenarios that holds true, but does that exclude the related-key attacks on (full, 64-round) TEA from being security issues? After all, between a  (full) cipher that suffers from a related-key attack and one that does not, would you not choose the one that does not for a practical purpose? I am of course referring to the 64-round versions of both TEA and XTEA. Should, any more severe attacks on full 64-round XTEA surface, I will be the first to admit I was wrong.

Comment: SHA family of hash functions are based on block ciphers significantly simpler than AES. Maybe you would like to implement SHA-1/-256/-512 or SHACAL-1/-2 (construct to use the block cipher within SHA-1/-2 as encryption algorithm).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple block cipher would be [Threefish](http://www.skein-hash.info/sites/default/files/skein1.3.pdf) (p. 11-13). It's a bit more complicated than RC4 or RC5 yet doesn't drive you insane with seemingly random design choices. It is presumably secure and was designed by experts but has not yet been reviewed extensively, so it shouldn't be used in sensitive applications yet (consider it an exercise).

You'll be able to implement the key schedule and the encryption/decryption functions, and if you use the PDF I linked above, it will be an excellent exercise in following a specification.

If anything, it's the technical details surrounding the implementations that can take you forever to fix, such as endianness concerns in particular (this isn't too much of a hassle for block ciphers but it did get in my way a few times when implementing hash functions).

PS: same name lol

Comment: I'm curious as to what you meant when you said "it is a priori secure."

Comment: @mikeazo I meant that it's been designed by cryptography experts and has undergone some analysis. So we can expect it to be secure, however it would be wise to wait until the algorithm has undergone more extensive peer review (better be safe than sorry). Perhaps I should edit my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Probably the only "a priori secure" function we have is a OTP.

Comment: Bad choice of terms, I agree. I don't know why I wrote that. Make that "presumably".

Comment: I found threefish easy enough to implement *directly from the specification*. It's fun to do, and you can compare with the reference implementation afterwards. The only tricky part (where the designers *themselves* went wrong) is taking care of the little endianness of the various values (up to 128 bit going the wrong way).

Comment: Ok, this is confusing. Thomas asked, and Thomas answered. lol

Answer (score 7):

As Thomas mentions, Threefish (especially Threefish-256) is reasonably straightforward to implement and has an excellent specification (and if you grab the [Skein 1.3 SHA-3 submission](http://www.skein-hash.info/sites/default/files/NIST_CD_102610.zip), comprehensive test vectors with intermediate states to help debug the implementation as you go).

One of the Speck family of block ciphers (published by the NSA in [The SIMON and SPECK Families of Lightweight Block Ciphers](http://eprint.iacr.org/2013/404)) would also be a good starting point - they're similar to Threefish in design approach, but simpler to implement, and the specification is well written (with good diagrams and pseudocode).  Obviously given the newness of Speck, and its provenance I'd strongly suggest these are implemented as an exercise only.

There are a bunch of Speck variants (differing in block size and key size), so I'd recommend to pick one of the smaller ones to start with.
Test vectors are a little light, and the spec is ambiguous about byte sequencing in input/output blocks, but you can use [my Java implementation](https://github.com/timw/bc-java/blob/feature/simon-speck/core/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/crypto/engines/SpeckEngine.java) to test against or generate intermediate states to help debug.

Answer (score 6):

I think that a stream cipher would be the natural progression from a Vinegère, (before moving onto a block cypher).

ARC4 (also known as ArcFour, or RC4) would be my choice and there are good argument for that made by Arnold Reinhold over on http://ciphersaber.gurus.org/

Comment: RC4 indeed. There's even a rumor that it's designed for soldiers to remember by head and implement whenever given a PC and directly use it to encrypt/decrypt messages.

Answer (score 6):

There is a stream cipher called the [Solitaire Cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solitaire_%28cipher%29) that is designed to be implemented by a human using only a deck of playing cards. It is very simple to memorize, use, and implement in code.

Comment: But AFAIK even weaker than RC4.

Answer (score 2):

If one looks for smallest code, [Tweetcipher](http://cybermashup.com/2013/06/12/tweetcipher-crypto-challenge/) might be interesting. There have been no third-party cryptanalysis, but it looks (for me) secure enough for exercise purpose.

Comment: [Simeck](https://gist.github.com/zhuzhuor/6206744) fits in one tweet (compared with Tweetciphers massive 6). It purports to be a combination of Simon and Speck and was presented at DIAC 2013 by [Bo Zhu](http://about.bozhu.me) (slides are on his page), but I'm not sure if it's serious...

Comment: @archie: Did you maybe mean to say that the [SPECK128 cipher fits in one tweet](https://gist.github.com/zhuzhuor/5c63c8716f9e51f9e088) ?

Comment: @archie: Did you maybe mean to link to the Simeck tweet on p. 23 of ["Revisiting Counter Mode to Repair Galois/Counter Mode and Simeck: An Authenticated Cipher Design"](http://2013.diac.cr.yp.to/slides/zhu.pdf)?